# Linking in wordpress, which link is right?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, hyperlink, echo

Which link version is right - if any?

```
<a href="<?php echo get_home_url( null, 'contact-us/', null); ?>">contact-us</a>
<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/contact-us">contact-us</a>
```

and image links:

```
<img alt="xxx" src="<?php echo get_home_url(null, 'fl-images/banner/teaser.png', null); ?>">
<img alt="xxx" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/fl-images/banner/svatebni-teaser.png">
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where exactly you wish to use this?

Comment: I don't understand what the need of the first version is, why make it more confusing for those reading it?

Comment: Im adjusting some pages like 404, woo categories etc. I had all links hard coded, but I decided to change it.

Comment: But why even consider version 1, what is wrong with the second version - it is much more intuitive to read.

Comment: they both correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<a>` tag use.

`<a href="<?php echo home_url('/kontakty'); ?>">kontakty</a>`

For `<img>` tag use.

`<img alt="xxx" src="<?php echo home_url('/fl-images/banner/svatebni-teaser.png'); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

In your case both will work assuming `fl-images` is in the public root.

However, if you want to reference a blog id or add a scheme to the home URL context then you can use the arguments. eg: `get_home_url( 2, 'contact-us/', 'https');`.

See [docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/)

Comment: I know that both versions works. Main idea of my question is which version is more proper.

Comment: I answered that in saying that it depends, both ways are proper. Up to you.